# Count rows where user has multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of transactions that records the person that made the purchase. I want the number of people that have had more than one transaction. The part I became stuck at is how do I specify that `Member` must match at least twice (e.g. two or more transactions)?

I figured it'd be something along the lines of

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE COUNT(`Member`)>2
```

but I realize that isn't a proper usage of the second count.

To further clarify: I want the result to be a single row that contains the number of users that this condition matches. So I don't want it to return how many times it matches per user or anything like that.

Comment: did you try it ?? what error did it return?

Comment: #1111 Invalid use of group function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) totalMember
FROM
(
    SELECT Member 
    FROM `table` 
    GROUP BY Member
    HAVING COUNT(Member) > 2 
) a
```